# Compression of JSON documents in Couchbase

Tags: json, compression, couchbase, snappy

In our application we are storing JSON documents in Couchbase which have a structure something  like this:

{
   "type": "sometype",
   "timestamp": 1458999,
   "data": "{\"key1\":\"val1\", \"key2\":\"val2\"}"
}

The value of the `data` field is a `stringified` json document which is quite huge, around 5-10MB of text. We have put it as a string(stringified json) instead of json subdocument so that it does not suffer serialisation/deserialisation while moving through different layers of the application since we need to just put and fetch it raw and supply to the client from the application.

The concern is would couchbase compress the stringified json while writing to disk. I am not sure whether couchbase compression is a kind of text compression or is it some kind of compression which can compress only json documents?

Comment: What is the rationale for your concern? I would ask if you have done a feature comparison on other NoSql database platforms as 5-10mb is large for CB (the hard limit is 20mb, so you are already halfway there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Couchbase will compress the document when storing it on disk.

When documents are stored on disk they are simply treated as a array of bytes which is compressed using the snappy compression algorithm.